# thymeleaf - how to test a string with "<p></p>"

Tags: thymeleaf

I want to test if a variable is not equal to

> < p>< /p>

(I put spaces before p and / here otherwise it wont show, in my case there is no space)

I did :  `<span th:if="${myString!='&lt;p&gt;&lt;/p&gt;'} ">`
But it doesn't work.

What is the right syntax?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are comparing Strings thus `!=` is not the right condition. User `.equals()` and just negate it. Replace your code with this:

```
<span th:if="${!myString.equals('&lt;p&gt;&lt;/p&gt;')} ">
```